# Visual Studio Task Runner, bind scripts to run with project simultaneously

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015, in Task Runner, we have four bindings: before and after build, clean, project open.

How can I bind to **Project Start**? I mean, when project starts, some scripts also starts, like this.

Comment: 'after build' is not sufficient?

Comment: @Daniel it doesn't work with client-side files, only with c# files.

Comment: I think it is impossible here, only After build